# Android Jsoup - login to page with aspx

Tags: android, asp.net, jsoup

I'm trying to log to [this website](https://cufs.vulcan.net.pl/lublin/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2Flublin%2FFS%2FLS%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0%26wtrealm%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fuonetplus.vulcan.net.pl%252flublin%252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%26wctx%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fuonetplus.vulcan.net.pl%252flublin%252fLoginEndpoint.aspx) using Jsoup in Android. Using webbrowser, after login, it is shows [this page](https://uonetplus.vulcan.net.pl/lublin/Start.mvc/Index). But my code shows another page titled "Working...". Problem is aspx, I think. Could You help, hot to login to propper page?

```
private void sendPostRequest() {
    try {
        Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://cufs.vulcan.net.pl/lublin/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2Flublin%2FFS%2FLS%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0%26wtrealm%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fuonetplus.vulcan.net.pl%252flublin%252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%26wctx%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fuonetplus.vulcan.net.pl%252flublin%252fLoginEndpoint.aspx")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        Connection.Response document = Jsoup.connect("https://cufs.vulcan.net.pl/lublin/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2Flublin%2FFS%2FLS%3Fwa%3Dwsignin1.0%26wtrealm%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fuonetplus.vulcan.net.pl%252flublin%252fLoginEndpoint.aspx%26wctx%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fuonetplus.vulcan.net.pl%252flublin%252fLoginEndpoint.aspx")
                .data("LoginName", LOGIN_STRING)
                .data("Password", PASSWORD_STRING)
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
        System.out.println("=============================================");
        System.out.println(document.parse());

        Connection.Response working = Jsoup.connect("https://cufs.vulcan.net.pl/lublin/")
                .cookies(document.cookies())
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

        System.out.println("=============================================");
        System.out.println(working.parse());

        Document indexDoc = Jsoup.connect("https://uonetplus.vulcan.net.pl/lublin/Start.mvc/Index")
                .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                .post();

        System.out.println("=============================================");
        System.out.println(indexDoc);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the userAgent string of your browser to the requests you are sending.

Comment: I added this "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.91 Safari/537.36". Nothing changed...